# Existence of an uniformly continuous function on an incomplete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

**Suppose**  $(X,d)$ is  an  incomplete  metric  space. Prove  that  there  exist  a  uniformly  continuous  function  $$f\ \colon\ \ X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$$  such  that  $$\inf_{x\in X}  f(x)=0.$$
**This is what I did.**
Now  since  completion  of  $X$  does  exist  so  taking  any  cauchy  sequence  $\{x_n\}$ we   can  find  the  limit, say,  $x_0$ in  the  completion . Define  the  function  $$f(x)=x-x_0.$$ Then  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)=0$$

But  what  assures  that  it  will  not  take  values  less  than  $0$? And  what  about  uniformity  of  the  function?

So  I  think  what  I  came  up  with  is  useless.

How  to  prove  it  then?
Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: You cannot write $x-x_0$ if there is no subtraction in $X$.

Comment: But, I would not say that what you came up with is useless, if you can find some good substitute for the expression $x-x_0$...

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X’, d’)$ be a completion of the space $(X,d)$. Since the space $(X,d)$ is incomplete, there exists a point $x_0\in X'\setminus X$. Put $f(x)=d’(x,x_0)$ for all $x\in X$. Then $f(X)\subset (0,\infty)$ and the triangle inequality for the metric $d’$ and condition $d’|X\times X=d$ imply uniform continuity of the function $f$. The density of the set $X$ in the space $X'$ imply that $\inf_{x\in X}f(x)=0$.